# Custom configuration layer for multi-term is ignored

Tags: spacemacs, use-package

I've created a new configuration layer (read more about it below) for multi-term but the settings specified there don't seem to apply.

Here is the code in particular

```
;;; packages.el --- rgp-multi-term Layer packages File for Spacemacs

(defun rgp-multi-term/init-multi-term ()
  "Initialize rgp-multi-term"
  (use-package multi-term
    :commands multi-term
    :defer t
    :init
    (progn
      (setq multi-term-program "/bin/zsh")
      (add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda() (setq yas-dont-activate t))))))
```

Multi-term itself works fine, but when I check for the value of `multi-term-program` it returns `nil`
So just to clarify, my problem is that the settings I specify in my configuration layer aren't applying.

I successfully added many other layers but I'm having some kind of problem with this one in particular.

Any ideas what's going on?

Thanks!

NOTE: A [configuration layer](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/doc/DOCUMENTATION.org#configuration-layers) is an Spacemacs specific term. It's basically a place to place some settings for a particular package. It uses the same syntax as the [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-packageg&sig2=ol0vXe7LI_QJ3TdGCO9B9Q) package.

Comment: Please clarify the problem and try to make you question self-contained.  (Incidentally, I think "layer" may be a spacemacs-specific term that will be unknown to most Emacs users.)

Comment: You're right. `Configuration-layer` is a spacemacs-specific term. Certainly it will be unknow to most Emacs users, but that's why I tagged the question as `Spacemacs`.

Comment: By "self-contained," I meant could you please post the specific code snippets that are giving you trouble?  You'll probably get more help if people don't have to follow links to your commits.

Comment: I'm not sure you can have more than one `use-package` for a particular package. If you are using the shell layer you may already have a `use-package multi-term` section. I'm not sure about this which is why this is a comment rather than an answer. But you might want to look into it.